How can I take a photo of an art project without getting a reflection of the camera in it?
I'm trying to photograph a triptych of three photos in a shiny gold frame (see sketch). I tried aiming diffused lights at it and covering everything in front of it (including the tripod) with black cloth to minimize reflections. The camera was only barely reflected in it, in the glass over the middle photo, which was good -- but the frames came out way too dark. They're barely recognizable as gold frames, because there was no light to speak of reflecting off them, since everything in front of them was covered in black cloth.
I tried adjusting the levels of the gold frames in Photoshop, but they're too dark for that to work.
I researched this issue online. The most common suggestion was to put a sheet of translucent white plastic in front of the triptych, light it from behind, put the camera behind it, and cut out a hole for the lens. This suggestion works passably well if you're photographing a curved object (because the camera's reflection will be distorted), or, say, a brushed-metal object (because the reflection will be diffused), but I don't believe that it will work in this case, because the reflection of the lens will be very obvious over the middle photo.
Another suggestion was to move the camera farther away from the object and zoom in on it, to reduce the size of the reflection, but that won't work in this case because a) I don't have a telephoto lens, and b) the object is fairly small (less than 20" wide).

I asked AI (!), but it gave me the same suggestions.
Is there a way to get this to come out right?

Is this a dup? How to photograph glass without reflections and shadows?

The issue here is how do I get the frame to come out looking gold, while still not getting a reflection of the camera in the glass.

The answer is basically in the link provided by Danielillo; photograph the frame from an angle and correct the keystoning effect in post. The farther away you can photograph it from, the less correction will be required.

That wouldn't be an acceptable fix. Since the frame extends in front of the photos, the perspective on the rectangular openings in it around the photos would be wrong, and wouldn't be fixed by adjusting the keystoning in post.

I'm thinking maybe I need to do some kind of composite: one shot with the correct lighting on the frame, and another shot with the correct lighting on the photos. Then combine the two in post.

I second that thought. I routinely shoot fine art (oil paintings) using a polarizer to get rid of the glare, and since the polarizer basically makes the gold leaf on frames disappear, I composite two otherwise identical shots using masks.

I'm going to take my own suggestion and try compositing two shots.

Here's how I ended up doing it:
I set up lights on either side of the artwork, aiming toward a piece of white foam board which is in front of the camera. The foam board has a hole cut in it for the camera to shoot through. The foam board lights up the gold frames nicely, so that they're appropriately bright and gold-looking. I aligned the camera to shoot the artwork very slightly off-axis, so that the reflection of the hole in the white board ended up in a uniformly dark area of the middle photo.
If the slight keystoning is noticeable, I'll adjust it in post. I'll also paint out the reflection of the hole, and adjust the reflection of the white board on the glass over the photos so that it essentially disappears.
Thanks to all for your suggestions!


If the camera must be square to the frame the correct tool is a shift lens. A shift lens can be placed off to the side so as not to reflect, but not require being tilted. They are used to photograph off center subjects without tilting in order to eliminate keystoning (e.g. architecture).
Here is an example of one being used to photograph a mirror perpendicular to the camera without its' reflection showing.

If that is not possible due to time/budget, and fixing keystoning in post is not an option, then the only other solution is compositing multiple images.
Note that if you have excess resolution you may be better off photographing the frame from farther away where perspective shifts are less apparent. That way you can composite images with the camera slightly left and slightly right; to eliminate the reflection when composited and it not be apparent.

You can solve the reflection problem with off-camera flash. Light the subject from the left and or the right at about a 45° angle. If you put a lot of light on the subject and reduce your exposure accordingly, the reflected image of the camera will fade into insignificance. Here is a diagram using this technique for shiny tombstones, although I have used it for photos under glass. Just make sure that the reflected light from the subject does not strike the camera or it will be visible again. You can control this with the distance and angles of the flash. The key is for the flash(es) to be at least as far back from the subject as the camera.

The only approach that I can think of, is using multiple shots with moved lights to combine into one shot with using the non reflection parts of the images as fills for the parts obscured with reflection.
This way you can also make sure that you get the best lighting on the frame, and have separate lighting for the photos where you just want to have no reflection of the camera and lights.
You might need to take the photo a bit on an angle and then rectify the geometry in post production, so that you have no reflection of the camera itself in the glass.
If the frame is protruding a lot at the edges of the image, this can be a problem. In that case, only try using the portion of the image that directly has the camera reflection.
Or remove the glass if you can, for the shooting. That is done quite often if a model wears glasses. However, you often don't have the luxury of being able to remove the glass from artworks.
